# Theaming and style in Android

Tags: android, themes, android-styles

I style a theme using Android asset studio. and i set my app theme in my manifest file.
here my all layouts background color is white i want to change that into some other color. i need to mention my all layout background color in my Style.xml...
how we can do that...

```
<style name="Theme.Jwellers" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.</item>
                <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
        <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.mytheme.Widget</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the color saved as a `drawable` just add

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/drawableNameOfColor</item>
```

That should make the background color whatever you have assigned to the `drawable` `drawableNameOfColor`

Comment: yaa i put this in my style.. but it make all element's background to that particular color. i need to set my layout background color only

even Action bar icon's background color also changed to that color